# Calculate the variance of Continuous Random Variables and the Distribution of a geometrical shape

Tags: geometry, variance, continuous-variables

I would like to compute the variance of a continuous random variables distribution that has the following form:

[image]

When "a" becomes as small as zero, the parallelogram will become a rectangle, in this case, the variance should be zero, then high variance when "a" is large, and then variance go back to zero when "a" is very very large

However, when I integrate the CDF function I don't get zero variance at all.
Below is my CDF (f(x)):

x  --> 0 < x < a (red segment)

1/(b-a) --> a < x < a+b (blue segment)

x-b --> b < x < a+b (green segment)

I used the following variance equation, but I didn't get zeros variance when X was zero

[image]

What did I do wrong here? I appreciate your advice and suggestions

Comment: By "variance" do you mean that term as used in probability? If so it's hard to see why you'd associate it to the shape of a parallelogram.

Comment: I updated the question for more clarity, basically, I want to compute the variance of Continuous Random Variables that has this form

Comment: A random variable has no shape such as a parallelogram. One may define a collection of parallelograms and some kind of randomized method to select a parallelogram from that collection. Once that has been done one might further define some real number related to the parallelogram shape to calculate from a typical parallelogram of the collection. Then of course that real number may be viewed as a random variable. But your description of your set-up does not explain any of this.